# Mathematically prove the data has been decorrelated

Tags: mathematical-statistics, autocorrelation

I have been using a pre whitenening technique to remove autocorrelation from my time series model which has a variable that are autocorrelating with itself over time. But I wondered how I could mathematically prove that my data is now decorrelated and if someone has any research paper that explains it or anything similar? Any help is apprecitiated

Comment: Is your time series wide-sense stationary?

Comment: The mean of the data varies quite a bit based on the time period so it doesn't seem so. I can also add that the data consists of electricity prices for a region on a week to week basis over several years.